# Symfony2 import data into

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I've inherited a Symfony2 app that is about 90% finished, and am at a point at which I need to import some data into the application from an old system. This is not an import of test data, but historical data from a previous application, which has been provided to me in a pipe-delimited DSV file. Basically, that means that I need to reverse-engineer the relationships of each row

I'm guessing the best way to do this is through doctrine's data-fixtures. I've found http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

I'm guessing the best way to go about this is to get access to the Container inferface to be able to access the entitymanager so that I can create new objects and then populate them with values from the DSV? How does mapping of those entity relationships work from within a data-fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures is static data for tests. It used when some one 'installing' you software (it created for it, for example base admin \ moderator \ user entries and theirs roles etc.)

BTW no need to use standalone bundles (such as fixtures) - just read about console commands - you easily can do your own.

You can do this way... Create a specific bundle or controller that will convert old data to new only if *some_file* exist. If it's needed only once you can do this locally, after conversion - delete this code.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I know that I can just write some scripts to shove the data from the DSV into my database. Using fixtures would allow me to associate that data properly, and it's the only way I know of to keep it usable.

Comment: As I said, you can create custom console command (fixture like) or use method in custom controller. I don't know how you want insert into db your data ( telepathically? :) ). Even if you will find some kind of parser you STILL have to create method where it will be described. =\ So solution only one, fixture\method - single call - done.